# How to use data outside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, tsx

In the variable **const user** inside `useEffect` function, I get an user object, I want to use the id, firstname and lastname from the user object in textfield. Is it somehow possible to use the user object outside the `useEffect` function?

In the code below the user object is undefined when used outside the `useEffect`.

- Any help is appreciated!

---

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

interface userData {
    id: number;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
};

const [obj, setObj] = useState();
const location = useLocation<userData>();
useEffect(() => {
    const user = allUsers.filter((obj) => obj.id === location.state.id);
    // handling if user is undefined
    if(user) {
        console.log('Storing object data')
        setObj(user);
    } else {
        console.log('No data!');
    }
}, [location]);
```

---

```
return (
        <div>
            <h1>User Data</h1>
            {/*Text field - id*/}
            <TextField
               name="id"
               id="id"
               label="ID"
               value={obj.id}
               fullWidth
             />
             {/*Text field - firstname*/}
             <TextField
               name="firstname"
               id="firstname"
               label="First Name"
               value={obj.firstname}
               fullWidth
             />
             {/*Text field - lastname*/}
             <TextField
               name="lastname"
               id="lastname"
               label="Last Name"
               value={obj.lastname}
               fullWidth
             />
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns an array. Probably you want to use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead. Also in either case I would update with `setObj()` your state because you can handle `null` in `return` also with `obj && obj.id`.

Try the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const user = allUsers.find((obj) => obj.id === location.state.id);
    setObj(user);
}, [location]);
```

Then in your `return`:

```
return <div>
   <h1>User Data</h1>
   {/* Showing TextField only if obj is not null */}
   { obj && <TextField name="id"
                       id="id"
                       label="ID"
                       value={obj.id}
                       fullWidth />}
</div>
```

I hope this clarifies!